# How do I change the UI of modules in Apache ofbiz

Tags: html, xml, erp, ofbiz

I was working on the Apache ofbiz(17.12.07) since last 1 month, I have a custom UI requirement for a client. I want to display a side-bar(screenshot of sibe-bar attached below) in all the ofbiz modules.
I have created a plugin called **HOME** in ofbiz. this **HOME** plugin contains a header,side-bar,container,footer.

I have created a .ftl file for this.
my requirement is to display the same header,sidebar,footer in all the module pages and the container will change according to the module content.

If the modules are ftl files then I could modify the UI but  they are xml files not the ftl.
clicking on the modules in the sidebar will take you to the respective module.

**example:** when I click on Asset maintenance in home page. we'll direct to Asset maintenance page. the container which is of grey color is the xml file as shown below.

**container xml:**

```
<screen name="FindScreenDecorator">
        <section>
            <widgets>
                <section>
                    <condition>
                        <if-empty field="titleProperty"/>
                    </condition>
                    <widgets>
                        <container style="page-title"><label text="${title}"></label> 
                        </container>
                    </widgets>
                    <fail-widgets>
                        <container style="page-title"><label 
                        text="${uiLabelMap[titleProperty]}"></label></container>
                    </fail-widgets>
                </section>
                <decorator-section-include name="menu-bar"/>
                <container style="clear"/>
                <screenlet id="searchOptions" name="findScreenlet" collapsible="true" 
                 title="${uiLabelMap.CommonSearchOptions}">
                    <container id="search-options">
                        <decorator-section-include name="search-options" />
                    </container>
                </screenlet>
                <screenlet padded="false">
                    <label style="h3" text="${uiLabelMap.CommonSearchResults}"/>
                    <container id="search-results">
                        <decorator-section-include name="search-results"/>
                    </container>
                </screenlet>
            </widgets>
        </section>
    </screen>`
```

**home page screenshot:**
[home_page_template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Widq.png)

**Asset maintenance module Ui screenshot:**
[Asset_maint_Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TATYz.png)

**layout of Ui:**
[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8T3i.png)

**code for home page:**

```
<div class="screenlet-body">
    <#if !userLogin?has_content>
      <div>${uiLabelMap.WebtoolsForSomethingInteresting}.</div>
      <br />
      <div>${uiLabelMap.WebtoolsNoteAntRunInstall}</div>
      <br />
      <div><a href="<@ofbizUrl>checkLogin</@ofbizUrl>">${uiLabelMap.CommonLogin}</a></div>
    </#if>
    <#if userLogin?has_content>
      <ul class="webToolList" id="home">
         <li><a href="/manufacturing/control/main?externalLoginKey=ELf8650276-c0c1-4952-9936-fd87e090beff"><h2 id="production">${uiLabelMap.HOMEProduction}</h2></a></li>
         <li><a href="/facility/control/main?externalLoginKey=ELfccd14d0-0b7b-4ded-844d-d8a9b950187c"><h2 id="inv">${uiLabelMap.HOMEInventoryManagement}</h2></a></li>
         <li><a href="/assetmaint/control/main?externalLoginKey=ELfccd14d0-0b7b-4ded-844d-d8a9b950187c"><h2 id="asset">${uiLabelMap.HOMEAssetMaintenance}</h2></a></li>
         <li><a href="/ordermgr/control/main?externalLoginKey=ELe412b3d4-a7a5-42a8-bc8c-9be077c664b9"><h2 id="order">${uiLabelMap.HOMEOrder}</h2></a></li>
         <li><a href="/partymgr/control/main?externalLoginKey=EL154c28ab-c21d-4004-8ab4-cc18d49bbe65"><h2 id="users">${uiLabelMap.HOMEUsers}</h2></a></li>
         <li><a href="/catalog/control/main?externalLoginKey=ELfccd14d0-0b7b-4ded-844d-d8a9b950187c"><h2 id="prodcatalog">${uiLabelMap.HOMEProductCatalog}</h2></a></li>
        
     </ul>
    </#if>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember having seen a such solution on OFBiz MLs or Jira. I'm pretty sure it was not using a plugins or any specific component. IIRW it was rather related to a theme. As I'm unsure you should better subscribe and ask on user ML: http://ofbiz.apache.org/mailing-lists.html. Here you ask to few persons who follow OFBiz questions, there to hundreds...

Comment: thanks for the information @JacquesLeRoux, your answer helped me to approach apache mailing lists, have mailed to the user mailing list of apache ofbiz. waiting for the reply there.